# Random number generation with Log-logistic and Burr distributions

Tags: r, random, netlogo, distribution

I am trying to generate distributions from real data. I used R package tdistrplus to get the parameters of the distributions. The distributions from the R package are: Pareto, Lognormal, Log-Logistic and Burr. However, I cannot find these distributions in NetLogo. I need to write a function for them. I have already found Pareto and Lognormal distributions in other forums:

```
;; Pareto distribution (Pareto from R package: tdistrplus)
to-report random-pareto [alpha mm]
report mm / ( random-float 1 ^ (1 / alpha) )
end

;; lognormal distribution (lnorm from R package: tdistrplus)
to-report log-normal [mu sigma]
let beta ln (1 + ((sigma ^ 2) / (mu ^ 2)))
let x exp (random-normal (ln (mu) – (beta / 2)) sqrt beta)
report x
end
```

However, I cannot find Log-logistic and Burr distributions completed functions or random number expressions, only probability density functions from which I do not know how to express X (Matchad cannot find the solution or I am using it incorrectly).

I would be grateful for any advice (to make a simulation based on real-data is necessary for my PhD thesis).

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What specifically do you want? generate random data from those distributions in R?

Comment: I want to model a supply chain in NetLogo by using distribution fitted on real-data to simulate demand variation.

In R I have used package tdistrplus to get the coefficients of the Burr and log-logistics distribution. I want to input those coefficients in NetLogo to simulate my real data. However, I do not know the function for Burr and Log-logistics to generate random data in Netlogo, in R they are built in.

E.g. output from R:
burr (shape1 = 0.9283009, shape2 = 2.3864253, rate = 1.0484444)
log-logistics (2.3224812 = 0.559 4916, scale = 0.9898947)

Comment: Generate random data in NetLogo by using Burr and log-logistics distributions

Comment: I haven't used Netlogo. Can you do everything in R?

Comment: Yes, its possible, but NetLogo is more user friendly and more suitable for simulation.

E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OogeV7q07cM&t=7s

Comment: "NetLogo is more user friendly" -- apparently not in this case. Especially for a Ph.D. thesis which involves probability, why not use the mathematically superior tool (R)? If you don't want to go that route -- look at the source code for those random number generators in R(or at the very least the documentation, which in the R world typically includes a citation of a published paper which contains the algorithm being implemented. Read the paper and implement the algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrt log-logistics, inverse CDF method should work fine. Following convention from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution)

```
to-report random-loglogistics [alpha beta]
    let r random-float 1
    let q r/(1-r)
    let x alpha exp (ln (q) / beta)
    report x
end
```

I quickly looked into sampling of Burr - could be done via inverse CDF as well. Following [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution)

```
to-report random-burr [c k]
    let r random-float 1
    let q exp ( - ln(r) / k) - 1
    let x exp ( ln(q) / c )
    report x
end
```

UPDATE

My NetLogo was once use LONG time ago, so let's just write some formulas and you could rewrite the code.

**Log-Logistics**

CDF(x | α, β) = (x/α)<sup>β</sup> / (1 + (x/α)<sup>β</sup>)

Inverse CDF means sample `x` using

x = CDF<sup>-1</sup>(r), where `r` is random uniform U(0,1)

Therefore, (x/α)<sup>β</sup> = q = r/(1-r), and
x = α q<sup>1/ β</sup>

**Burr**

CDF(x | c, k) = 1 - (1 + x<sup>c</sup>)<sup>-k</sup>

Inverse CDF means sample `x` using

x = CDF<sup>-1</sup>(r), where `r` is random uniform U(0,1)

(1 + x<sup>c</sup>)<sup>-k</sup> = r

(1 + x<sup>c</sup>) = (1/r)<sup>1/k</sup>

x = ((1/r)<sup>1/k</sup> - 1)<sup>1/c</sup>

Please check my math, and in the code all those powers were expressed via `exp` and `ln`. Conventions are according to wiki

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: I just have one more question. random-float requires one input, a number. What should I set it? I think it's important because sometimes I keep getting an error in burr distribution, stating that "Can't take logarithm of -0.008."

Comment: @ValentasGruzauskas Sorry, was using NetLogo once LONG time ago. Should be `random-float 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. You helped to put great added-value to my simulation. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation, need to renew my mathematical knowledge :)